# Writing out a list of strings to a file

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I have a list of abbreviations

Letters = ['Ala', 'Asx', 'Cys', ... 'Glx']

I want to output this to a text file that will look this like:

#Letters
Ala, Asx, Cys, ..... Glx

Noob programmer here! I always forget the simplest things! ah

please help and thanks!

```
import Bio
from Bio import Seq
from Bio.Seq import Alphabet

output = 'alphabetSoupOutput.txt'
fh = open(output, 'w')
ThreeLetterProtein = '#Three Letter Protein'
Letters = Bio.Alphabet.ThreeLetterProtein.letters
fh.write(ThreeLetterProtein + '\n')

  #Don't know what goes here

fh.close()
```

Comment: So you just want to write out the protein codes?  Or are you converting input sequence data to protein codes and trying to write that out?

Comment: "I always forget the simplest things!".  There's a trick.  It's called "bookmark the tutorial".  http://docs.python.org/tutorial/  It really doesn't cost anything to review.  And you might get an answer faster by reading the tutorial than posting here.

Answer (score 5):

How about `fh.write(', '.join(Letters))`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about the bio package but I guess ...

```
for letter in letters:
    fh.write(letter + ',')
```

or

```
fh.write(",".join(letters))
```